How to stop Azure CAF advertising 0.0.0.0 over ExpressRoute
When using the Azure CAF, at some point when your all setup and ready to go, you have to connect it to your organisation.
I imagine that simply plugging an Azure CAF platform that has a 0.0.0.0 route advertisement into a corporate network that already has a 0.0.0.0 would result in some undesired behaviour?
What would be the preferred/most correct way to stop 0.0.0.0 being advertised over ExpressRoute into your on-prem?
Should we attempt to atop the advertisement on the Azure side, or filter the BGP on the on-prem networking side?
The doc doesn't really seem to have much to say on the subject.
Has anyone had to deal with this?

Any code you tried so far? @Scott

Hi. No code as such, was more of a general approach/method type question. I'm in the camp that thinks the onus should be on the comms/network vendor side to filter (as they will typically have access to actual routing hardware rout(er|ing) kit. Another person in the team feels that we should prevent Azure advertising routes out to the network vendor.

can you  check with this answer by Ganesh Patapati  addressing the relevent issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2072598/on-premises-expressroute-bgp-is-advertising-0-0-0 @scott


Stoping Azure CAF advertising 0.0.0.0 over ExpressRoute

There is no better direct way to fix this from our end Azure doesn't have native outbound route filtering so to manage this from the on premises BGP configuration is approach we can say.
So, the final conclusion of the requirement mentioned is that there is no better way to do this other than to fix it with the correct BGP on-premises and move on.
To do this from on-premisus side

configure filters to prevent 0.0.0.0/0 default route
Try using BGP route maps or prefix lists this will stops default route from azure

demo configuration:
route-map BLOCK_DEFAULT_ROUTE deny 10
  match ip address prefix-list DEFAULT_ROUTE
route-map ALLOW_OTHER_ROUTES permit 20

ip prefix-list DEFAULT_ROUTE seq 5 permit 0.0.0.0/0

router bgp <YOUR_AS_NUMBER>
  neighbor <AZURE_PEER_IP> route-map BLOCK_DEFAULT_ROUTE in

Refer:
On-premises expressroute BGP is advertising 0.0.0.0/0 and using Azure Firewall to control traffic (including internet) - Microsoft Q&A answered by Ganesh Patapati .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-routing
